# Python delta for 7 day difference

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, that I am wanting to calculate the delta over a 7 day time period:

```
  Monday   Tuesday   Wednesday   Thursday   Friday    Sat     Sun   

  5        10         15         20         25        30      35

  1        2          3           4         5         6       7
```

I would like to find the delta for the first row, starting with Monday (5) and ending on Sun (35)

*The delta for the first 7 day time period would be:*   **35 - 5 = 30**

*The next 7 day window delta would be:*    **7 - 1  = 6** and so on

The date would ***begin on 1/1/2020*** and ***continue by 7 day or weekly increments*.**

Desired output: (New dataframe with the newly created Date and Delta columns)

```
   Date                  Delta

   1/1/2020              30
   1/8/2020              6
```

This is what I am doing:

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np

  df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

  df['Delta'] = df['Sunday'] - df['Monday]
  df['Date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', periods=len(df), freq='Weeks')




 df2.to_csv('df2.csv')
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets Try calculate `date_range` by incorporating multiples in the `freq`

```
df['Delta']=df.Sun.sub(df.Monday)
df['Date']=pd.Series(pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'), periods=7, freq='7d'))
```

or simply

```
df=df.assign(Delta=df.Sun.sub(df.Monday),Date=pd.Series\
(pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'), periods=7, freq='7d')))



  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday  Sat  Sun  Delta       Date
0       5       10         15        20      25   30   35     30    2020-01-01
1       1        2          3         4       5    6    7      6     2020-01-08
```

Comment: This is helpful. Let me try this as well. Thank you @wwnde
Is there a way to make new dataframe with just the Date and Delta (and not include the other days Mond-Sunday?)

Comment: Hi @wwnde this works, but is there a way to just have the newly created columns: Delta and Date?

Comment: Yap, by just calling the list of columns at the end. Please try `df=df.assign(Delta=df.Sun.sub(df.Monday),Date=pd.Series\
(pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'), periods=7, freq='7d')))[['Delta','Date']]`

Comment: One more question. Lets say I didnt know the column names and I wanted to used Delta with Indexing. Would I just Delta=df[8].sub(df.[0]) ??? Could I do this too? @wwnde

Comment: Use the interger loc accessor, `df['Delta']=df.iloc[:,6].sub(df.iloc[:,0])`, `i` stand for integer, `:` means all rows, `0` and `6` are the column indices

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you abundantly

Comment: @wwnde how come there's not an error for `pd.Series(pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp("2020-01-01"), periods=7, freq="7d"))` being greater than the two rows needed?

Comment: @baxx I believe thats what `pd.Series` does. It locks  the output to existing index. from documentation `Labels need not be unique but must be a hashable type. The object supports both integer- and label-based indexing and provides a host of methods for performing operations involving the index. Statistical methods from ndarray have been overridden to automatically exclude missing data (currently represented as NaN).`

Comment: Hello @wwnde  - what if my data were vertical as in:  Date and Value are both columns - How would I apply this code?  Could you please respond to my latest post with this? I am researching this as well

Answer (score 1):

```
# necessary imports
import datetime
import pandas
```

Can do:

```
numdays=5
base = datetime.datetime(2020,1,1)
date_list = [base + datetime.timedelta(days=7*x) for x in range(numdays)]
```

Then:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':date_list})
```

If you have another list of values, ie `Deltas_list` you want to include in this dataframe:

```
Deltas_list=[0,1,2,3,4]
Deltas=pd.Series(Deltas_list)
df['Delta']=Deltas
```

df will be:

```
    Date    Delta
0   2020-01-01  0
1   2020-01-08  1
2   2020-01-15  2
3   2020-01-22  3
4   2020-01-29  4
```

Comment: Thank you- I will try. This code looks like it creates the date increments correct? Will it display the deltas as well?

Comment: No, not the deltas unfortunately. I didn't quite get what you mean by the deltas. Would you try to explain it to me in other words?

Comment: Yes- my apologies if I was not clear. It is just taking the delta of  any value that is in the day 1 column and any value that is in the day 7  column- day 1 is monday, day 7 is sunday

Comment: Oh ok! But if you are increasing the days in 7 day difference, all of them will be the same day (ie Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday or ...), so do you want all deltas to be the same?

Comment: Oh, deltas will not be the same though right, because there are different values within them

Comment: I don't get this part: 35 - 5 = 30;  7 - 1 = 6: where do these numbers (35,5,7,1) come from?

Comment: It is a large dataframe and the dataframe has certain values within the columns and rows. 35 is just a value that is under the Sunday column, and 5 is a value in the Monday column

Comment: Oh ok sorry got it now.

Comment: I perform the calculation correct, I just am unsure of how to include it in the new dataframe with the date generation

Comment: Edited my answer; if you can do the calculation and put the result to a list, it'll be useful, I hope.

Comment: sure- let me try. I believe this is helpful- thank you